# How do I position a png over another image and still be able to interact with both?

Tags: html, css

I am building a portfolio website and I want a mockup on top of a background but when I hover over the mockup I cannot interact with the background. I want them to both scale, but the mockup should scale more than the background, therefore I need a :hover on both of them separately.

I tried fiddling around with the z-index but it did not work out. Here is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W51HZ.jpg

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.try {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 80px 0px 60px 10px;
}

.bg {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.3);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.mockup {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.mockup:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="try">
  <div>
    <img class="mockup" src="img/mockup.png">
    <img class="bg" src="img/bg.jpg">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img class="mockup" src="img/mockup.png">
    <img class="bg" src="img/bg.jpg">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img class="mockup" src="img/mockup.png">
    <img class="bg" src="img/bg.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

I want both elements to be scaling separately, but the mockup blocks the background from scaling on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper div that triggers the hover, and assign different effects to `mockup` and `bg` like this:

```
.wrapper:hover .mockup {
    transform: scale(1.2);

}

.wrapper:hover .bg {
    transform: scale(5.0);

}
```

Full snippet: (You can see they both resize different)

```css
.try {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    margin: 80px 0px 60px 10px;
}

.bg {

    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214,214,214,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214,214,214,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(214,214,214,0.3);

    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.mockup {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;



    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .mockup {
    transform: scale(1.2);

}

.wrapper:hover .bg {
    transform: scale(5.0);

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <img class="mockup" src="img/mockup.png">
            <img class="bg" src="img/bg.jpg"> 
</div>
```